# How do I remove deckgl legend on shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, legend, dashboard, deck.gl

I am running into an issue with a shiny dashboard that I am trying to create, wherein updating a *deckgl* plot causes a new legend to append into the view as opposed to replacing the old legend. The legend also persists even when I completely re-render the plot.

The MVP below illustrates this issue, where changing the date input appends a new legend and fails to remove the old, in addition to the reset button failing to remove the legends as well. Although the legend contents do not change in this example, the full version of the dashboard have changing attributes including the colors, labels and title.

If anyone knows of a way to remove old legends from the plot view upon each `observeEvent` instance to stop the plot from being cluttered with old legends that refer to the wrong map_data, any help would be greatly appreciated!

TIA

```
#MVP - legend error 

#packages 
library(deckgl)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "a nice map"), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    dateInput(inputId = "date", label ="Select Date:", value = "2019-01-01",
              min = "2019-01-01", max = "2019-01-31"),
    actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset Map")), 
  dashboardBody(deckglOutput('map', height = "90vh"))
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$map <- renderDeckgl({
    
    deckgl(zoom = 10) %>% 
      add_basemap()})
  
  observeEvent(input$date, {
    
    #add a map layer that plots some data
    map_data <- input$date
    
    deckgl_proxy("map") %>%
      add_geojson_layer(data = map_data, 
      ) %>%
      add_legend(
        colors = "colour_pal", 
        labels = "colour_labs",
        pos = "bottom-left",
        title = "something", 
      ) %>%
      update_deckgl()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, 
               output$map <- renderDeckgl({
                 deckgl(zoom = 10) %>% 
                   add_basemap()})
               )

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```